# Client-Side timeout couchbase node js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, couchbase

I am trying to send few hundreds (448 to be exact) of small documents (20 KB each) to my Couchbase server which has been setup using [couchbase AMI](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B013XDO1B4/ref=sp_mpg_product_title?ie=UTF8&sr=0-2). I used the following code in Node.JS

```
var couchbase = require('couchbase');
var cluster = new couchbase.Cluster('couchbase://54.xx.xxx.xxx:8091');
var bucket = cluster.openBucket('myBucket', 'password', function(err) {
    if(err){
        console.log("Can't open bucket");
        throw err;
    }
    else {
        console.log("Successfully opened bucket");
    }
});
function addToDatabase(data) {
    var key = some key;
    bucket.upsert(key, data, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        console.log(result);

    });
}
```

It sends about 50 documents successfully and then gives me a timeout error:

```
{ [CouchbaseError: Client-Side timeout exceeded for operation. Inspect network conditions or increase the timeout]  message: 'Client-Side timeout exceeded for operation. Inspect network conditions or increase the timeout',  code: 23 }
```

I am using the latest version(2.1.2) of [couchnode](https://github.com/couchbase/couchnode).

I increased the timeout on bucket connection (bucket.operationTimeout=500*1000). After this change it sends all the documents successfully, but it is not a solution because I would not know what is the best value for operationTimeout.
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is the code running from? It feels like the client system might be resource bound or something. Your code looks right to me. Also, the newest version of the couchbase node.js SDK is 2.1.2, not 1.2.1.

Comment: Thanks for the note, fixed the version. I'm using IntelliJ to run the code on mac os x 10.11.1. I found if I do the database upserts one by one and wait for the results and then run the next one, it will run ok.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you are resource constrained on your client, like file descriptors (something MacOS is known to have not enough of), RAM, sockets, something. I bet if you were to spin up another AWS instance, you'd see this same code load your data in no time and get the access times you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue with CouchBase on AWS.
I solved it by opening the following ports to anyone:

22  tcp 0.0.0.0/0
4369    tcp 0.0.0.0/0
4984    tcp 0.0.0.0/0
8080    tcp 0.0.0.0/0
8088    tcp 0.0.0.0/0
8091    tcp 0.0.0.0/0
8092    tcp 0.0.0.0/0
11209   tcp 0.0.0.0/0
11210   tcp 0.0.0.0/0
11211   tcp 0.0.0.0/0
11214   tcp 0.0.0.0/0
11215   tcp 0.0.0.0/0
18091   tcp 0.0.0.0/0
18092   tcp 0.0.0.0/0

For more info see: http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.5/cb-install/#network-ports